# What is the interpretation of different formula in Multinom?

Tags: r, regression, multinomial, nnet

I want to run a multinomial logit regression using the multinom() function from the nnet R package. I need some help with the interpretation of different formulas. My dataset have 3 IV  (age (3 levels) , presonality(4 levels)and Test(2 levels))an 1 DV (response (4 levels)) and all variables are categorical.Here an example of the dataset.

```
>head(df)
        Personality   Age     Test     Response
1           1         50+     pre      A
2           1         50+     post     A
3           2         30-39   pre      B
4           2         50+     post     C
5           3         20-29   pre      D
6           3         20-29   post     A
```

First,I want to understand the effect of personality on users' response in different test. I wrote two formulas (find them below) but I do not know what are the different between them and how their results will be interpreted differently.
Eq1= multinom(formula= response~ test + personality, data=df) 
Eq2= multinom(formula= response~ test * personality, data=df)

Second, I want to understand how the result can be reported in paper?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Questions about interpretations of statistical models are not programming questions and do not belong no StackOverflow. You should ask such questions over at [stats.se].

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and for the notice.